# PHP xml get attribute value and then read entire line

Tags: php, xml, search

Hello I want to search in xml file attribute value, and if its found(result only can be 1) read entire line with other attributes, problem is that i kind fresh in xml, so don't judge me i tried to find information, but only nodes searching methods.

```
<?php
$ged =1;
$xmlStr = file_get_contents("data_map/data_output.xml"); 
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 
$res = $xml->xpath("markers/marker/id='. $ged .'"); 
echo $res; 

?>
```

My xml file which in attributes, but my php code only returns this error:

Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 7
Array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
  <marker id="1" name="Love.Fish" address="580 Darling Street, Rozelle, NSW" lat="-33.861034" lng="151.171936" type="restaurant" duty="very tall people"/>
  <marker id="2" name="house party" address="Information Centre" lat="55.499996" lng="25.608803" type="restaurant" duty="very kind people."/>
</markers>
```

I believe that is my query is not correct, and also after i got correct line, how to read it and put every attribute into different variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is not correct, you should use square brackets and an @ to filter on attributes.
Like so:

```
/markers//marker[@id=2]
```